# How to get IntelliSense for Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Just installed Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 and trying to create an MVC application with Razor View Engine.

When opened a ".cshtml" file, I am not able to get colors for syntaxes in editor and also intellisense is not appearing. Is there any option I explicitly need to enable it?

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATE:** The [Release Candidate](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx) finally supports Razor IntelliSense.
**Update2**: [The final release got announced here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx) and it also still supports Intellisense for Razor syntax. Woohoo!

Here's a screenshot of the new enhanced Intellisense and Razor syntax highlighting:

[image]

For a great overview/introduction to MVC3 and NuGet I suggest you take a look at this [PDC10 video](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/e0c3ce51-9869-456c-a197-63dc0283f57e).

*Previous Answer*

No. It doesn't work yet with the current beta:

> Razor intellisense isn't in today's
>   beta. We needed to do a little more
>   testing (and bug fixing) before we
>   were ready to distribute it broadly. 
>   It patches a few VS files and so we
>   need to make sure it is 100% solid
>   before giving it out broadly.
>
> It will definitely be in the final
>   release, though, and should be
>   available for people to install in the
>   next few weeks.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Scott

Taken from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/06/announcing-nupack-asp-net-mvc-3-beta-and-webmatrix-beta-2.aspx#7624491

Comment: Thanks. I have just gone through the article and noticed it.

Comment: If you were previously using MVC3 Beta and set a file extension association in Visual Studio between .cshtml/.vbhtml and the HTML editor (to get nice HTML colours), then you'll need to remove it before IntelliSense will work with MVC3 RC.

Comment: If you have any older version then you would need to completely uninstall it using steps given here: http://drew-prog.blogspot.in/2010/11/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-3.html and then install the latest version of MVC3

Answer (score 7):

You can get syntax highlighting by associating the `.cshtml` extension with the HTML editor in the Visual Studio properties (this will highlight only HTML tags and not Razor syntax). IntelliSense doesn't work yet. Microsoft will release an extension to Visual Studio which will support it in a later version.

[image: Screenshot].

Comment: How do you go about this, by the way?

Comment: @Stacey In Visual Studio you go: Tools->Options choose "Text Editor"->"File Extension" put cshtml in the extension text box and choose "HTML Editor" in the editor drop down.

Answer (score 7):

You can install a visual studio extension to get highlighting but not intellisense. [Razor Syntax Highlighter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/8dc77b9c-7c83-4392-9c46-fd15f3927a2e?SRC=Home)

Comment: Very cool! We used the parser to write something similar internally, but the full editor with IntelliSense takes a little more work :).  The full syntax editor is coming soon!

Comment: Yeah, I wrote that a few days ago but realized Intellisense was much more work than I was willing to commit. Especially since you guys would probably come out with a real version before I could finish it. There are still a few bugs with regards to parsing but it works well enough :)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC team has just released RC release for ASP.NET MVC 3 and it has intellisense for Razor engine. :)

Follow this link for more information:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The intellisense and syntax highlighting does not work in the current version. It is due to be fixed for the final release though.

Saw a demo from Scott Gu on Friday - the Razor View engine looks very cool.