# No Intellisense support for Razor Views (CSHTML)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Iam not able to get intellisense support for CSHTML files in VS 2010. It was working fine before, all of a sudden its driving me nuts..

Any Idea on what could have caused the issue ?  Even the View files in Visual Studio Solution Explorer are not displayed with "Razor View" icon.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491456/how-to-get-intellisense-for-razor-view-engine

Comment: I have reinstalled MVC 3 and its working now.

Comment: I uninstalled everything and re-installed them all, but still no success.