# .cshtml page and it's element in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to use  `@Html` helpers in my view,but Visual Studio does not know that my project is MVC4. I have set `Using System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: Duplicate of [Razor Intellisense Not Working VS2010 SP1Rel MVC3 from WPI Win7 x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133090/razor-intellisense-not-working-vs2010-sp1rel-mvc3-from-wpi-win7-x64), [IntelliSense won't work for MVC Razor cshtml page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481477/intellisense-wont-work-for-mvc-razor-cshtml-page), [How to get IntelliSense for Razor View Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491456/how-to-get-intellisense-for-razor-view-engine). Please use the search. At least please explain how you created the project and what exactly you have changed and tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing `<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />` within your `web.config` file under your Views folder

Please open web.config file Under Views folder and check if there the above tag is within `namespaces`, if not add it and you should be able to use `@Html` within your Razor views without manually referencing the library in every view

Comment: Yes I add there but it is red and unknown(my project has System.Web.Mvc)

Comment: Expand References in you project and see if there is any exclamation marks for System.Web.Mvc

Comment: Do you have the assembly included in the project as well?

Comment: yes,it is ok,Thank you Amila,after 4 min I can accept your response,Thank you again

Comment: I guess you started an Empty Mvc project, if you are a fist timer you'll scratch your head for a long time to figure out what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using Razor (*.cshtml) instead of Asp.Net (*.aspx) as the viewengine. You cant use `@Html` in Asp.Net viewengine views, there you should use `<% Html`